# How to get paragraph vector for a new paragraph?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word-embedding

I have a set of users and their content(1 document per user containing tweets of that user). I am planning to use a distributed vector representation of some size N for each user. One way is to take pre trained wordvectors on twitter data and average them to get distributed vector of an user. I am planning to use doc2vec for better results.But I am not quite sure if I understood the DM model given in [Distributed Representations of Sentences and Documents](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/le14.pdf).

I understand that we are assigning one vector per paragraph and while predicting next word we are using that and then backpropagating the error to update the paragraph vector as well as word vector. How to use this to predict paragraph vector of a new paragraph?

Edit : Any toy code for gensim to compute paragraph vector of new document would be appreciated.

Comment: there's a good explanation on quora about the training and prediction with the doc2vec model: https://www.quora.com/How-does-doc2vec-represent-feature-vector-of-a-document-Can-anyone-explain-mathematically-how-the-process-is-done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is based on gensim's doc2vec [tutorial](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb). We can instantiate and train a [doc2vec](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/le14.pdf) model to generate embeddings of size 300 with a context window of size 10 as follows:

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
model = Doc2Vec(size=300, window=10, min_count=2, iter=64, workers=16)
model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
```

Having trained our model, we can compute a vector for a new unseen document as follows:

```
doc_id = random.randint(0, len(test_corpus))
inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(test_corpus[doc_id])
sims = model.docvecs.most_simlar([inferred_vector], topn=len(model.docvecs))
```

This will return a 300-dimensional representation of our test document and compute top-N most similar documents from the training set based on cosine similarity.

Comment: Does anyone actually know how to compute the inferred vector? calling gensim's infer_vector doesn't answer the question imo.